# Paypal payflow pro notifyurl

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

On paypal payflow pro direct payment, on production, i am getting a Declined error from paypal. But, after a while, the payment gets processed.

What i am trying to do is to capture the payment and validate the invoice.

My plan is to use the NOTIFYURL feature to capture the payment but it doesen't seem to work.

On sandbox i am using the next call:

> USER=****&VENDOR=****&PARTNER=paypal&PWD=****&TENDER=C&TRXTYPE=S&ACCT=4111111111111111&EXPDATE=0217&NAME=test
>   name&CVV2=123&AMT=102&CURRENCY=USD&COMMENT1=Andrei&FIRSTNAME=Andrei&LASTNAME=Test&STREET=100
>   Testing Street&CITY=Colfax&STATE=North
>   Carolina&ZIP=27235&COUNTRY=US&CUSTIP=1.2.3.4&NOTIFYURL=https://***.domain.com/silent_post&VERBOSITY=MEDIUM

But i am not receiving a notification from paypal even tough the payment was successfully processed.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that the page at NOTIFYURL is working, i.e. tried visiting it in a browser?

Comment: Yes @DougMcLean, when i manually visit the notifyurl in the browser it records the request. I am recording any visit to that URL.

Comment: I know that sometimes PayPal sandbox can be a bit temperamental, e.g. in some cases you need to be logged in to sandbox.paypal.com in one browser tab and test the transaction in another tab. Does it work if you switch your dev site to connect to live PayPal?

Comment: @DougMcLean i am using Paypal payflow, so i am using a merchant account. Everything works fine, except the notifyurl.

Answer (score 0):

Payflow does not use the [notifyURL](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) as that's used with the doDirect classic APIs. That's why you're not getting the notif. Usually in most cases you can validate a pay request via the response from the payment; however if you want to take it a step further, you can use a [silentpost](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/?mark=silent%20post#passing-other-data-to-your-server-using-post-or-silent-post) method to take whatever the customer has submitted via the invoice and validate upon submission.